# Accessing COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME when using default

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Contrary to what the documentation for `docker-compose` [says](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/) I can't seem to access to value of `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` in my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      - "PROJECT_NAME=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

The variable isn't set to the default:

```
WARNING: The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
      PROJECT_NAME: ''
```

It's also not set when passing in `-p foobar`:

```
WARNING: The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
      PROJECT_NAME: ''
```

Are the only ways of having `COMPOSE_NAME_PROJECT` defined to either use `.env` file or setting it in the environment?

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying the same... it seems like the variable is not meant to be used in the compose-yaml but only to configure the docker-compose CLI:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/

You can nicely check variable interpolation using

`docker-compose config`